# Click on link to hide all other content divs

Tags: show-hide

Example:  (werkwijze is custom, i also have the same code with other names like -contact)

```
    $(function() {
        $('#activator-werkwijze').click(function(){
            $('#overlay-werkwijze').fadeIn('fast',function(){
                $('#box-werkwijze').animate({'bottom':'0px'},800);
            });
        });
        $('#boxclose-werkwijze').click(function(){
            $('#box-werkwijze').animate({'bottom':'-600px'},800,function(){
                $('#overlay-werkwijze').fadeOut('fast');
            });
        });
    });
```

activator shows the content, boxclose closes the content.
clicking all activators opens all content while it needs to open only one and close the others..

edit got it fixed:
This is the script which works, (the overlay is useless) jsfiddle.net/8y7Sr/126/

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more information about how you are calling the pop-up script.  If you are using jquery, you can just close all and then open one

```
$('.className').slideDown(200);
$('#specificItem').slideUp(200);
```

But again, you should explain how you are doing the calls in more detail for a better answer

Comment: i just took another look and you have a fundamental flaw in your code.  you are using the id attribute more than once within the DOM.  this is illegal and will result in errors.  fix this problem and instead of using the id to select the element, navigate the dom tree with jquery to select which element is on or off.  use http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/ and your issues will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

example, put inside function jQuery

if($('.hide').css('display')=='block'){ $('.hide').slideUp(); }else{ $('.hide').slideDown(); }

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('.activator').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            showHideAnimation(clickedObj);
        });
    });
}

function showHideAnimation(clickedObj)
{
    $('.activator').each(function(){
        if($(this).id == clickedObj.id) {
            $(this).fadeIn('fast',function(){
                $(this).animate({'bottom':'0px'},800);
            });
        } else {
            $(this).animate({'bottom':'-600px'},800,function(){
                $(this).fadeOut('fast');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Please try this if it doesn't work properly then replace **$(this)** with only **this**

Comment: i don't see in your script where #box-werkwijze gets opened. Im not a coder